# Downloading files from zip and extracting suddenly extracts random things?

Tags: zip, storage

I recently downloaded a gmod map of 5 mb and I got like 70 gb left as storage. Now I tried extracting the map to the desktop and all of a sudden it says:"Cant extract, need 11.7gb to extract" So I canceled and I looked at the storage again and it had 20 gb left. This is really weird and only happens with a zip file. What should I do to fix this and why is this happening? I cant find the files which are taking up the 50gb of storage.

Comment: What archive program are you using? Try opening the file and using its test function to check the file for corruption.

Comment: Its not just this file, had it with more files actually.

Comment: Did you check your temp-directory (`%temp%`)?

Comment: Where is the temp directory again?

Comment: Type [`%temp%` in the address bar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jVNVO.png) of an Explorer window.

Comment: @Synetech Empty. Nothing special or big.

Comment: What archive program are you using?

Comment: @Synetech Winrar. I have a feeling I have like 150 gb of this unnecessary space gone because of this problem.

Comment: Use something like spacesniffer to figure out where is all this space going..

Comment: @tumchaaditya still can't find where the files are hidden

Comment: There is no large folder? May be just try cleaning things up with CCleaner or Disk Cleanup